# View source of controller when control marked/hover

Tags: visual-studio-code

I started to write in html and some other web stuff, I chose to work with Visual Studio Code, I am looking for stuff than would make my work simpler, now I need the following:

I want that if I press/ hover on some button/label on the browser/ some other design mode, than VS Code would point me the relevant part of code of the label/button.

Is there extention for this? is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Google Chrome Dev tool for that. Press F12 ont the page, under Source...

Answer (score 1):

It's Common question from VS  code  official site:
Does VS Code have HTML preview?
No, VS Code doesn't have built-in support for HTML preview but there are extensions available in the VS Code Marketplace. Open the Extensions view (Ctrl+Shift+X) and search on 'live preview' or 'html preview' to see a list of available HTML preview extensions.